# Simplifying expressions and integrals with index notation

Tags: calculus, integration, vectors, tensors, index-notation

So I have a problem where I'm supposed to simplify the integral $$\oint_C(\mathbf{ r\cdot B)r \times dr},$$ where $\mathbf r=(x, y, z)$ and $\mathbf B$ is a constant vector, using index notation. I get it to $$\iint_S(dS_i\partial_m(r_pB_pr_m)-\partial_i(r_pB_pr_l)dS_l),$$ but I don't really understand how to handle the second part of it. The first one I'm able to simplify to $$3(\mathbf{r \cdot B})\mathbf {dS} + \mathbf {dS}(\mathbf r \cdot \nabla)(\mathbf{r \cdot B}),$$but from the second part I get $$[(\mathbf{r \cdot dS)\nabla(r \cdot B)}]_i + r_pB_p\partial_i(r_l)dS_l,$$ where I have no idea how to simplify the second expression.

I've come across this problem before in an excerecise where I was supposed to simplify $$\oint_C(\mathbf{A \times dr)},$$ but in the solution here they only gave the answer in the form $$\iint_S (\partial_jA_jdS_i-\partial_iA_jdS_j),$$ which doesn't really help much.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Since $\partial_i r_l = \delta_{il}$ and dummy indices are summed, the second term can be written as $$r_p B_p \delta_{il}dS_l = r_p B_p dS_i = (\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{B})[d\mathbf{S}]_i.$$

Comment: @Semiclassical Thank you! I've been stuck on this problem for way too long... But this is something that only works because $r_i=x_i$, right? There's no way to simplify an expression like $\partial_iA_jdS_j$, the expression in the other excercise? And this leads me to another question, why would you want to "simplify" the integral in the second excercise if you can't even write it in "vector form", so to say?

Comment: You're right that the simplification requires $r_i=x_i$. So in general the simplification needn't correspond to some 'nice' vector calculus expression. But I can imagine some applications. For instance, suppose $\vec{A}$ is the vector potential and we're working in Coulomb gauge so that $\nabla\cdot \vec{A}=0$. Then the answer they give tells you that only the second term matters. Or, suppose $\vec{A}$ points along the $z$-axis; then the second term simplifies to $\iint_S(-\nabla A_z)\,dxdy$.